# Find x for which $\sum\left[(n^3+1)^\frac13-n\right]x^n$ converges.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For what values of $x$ the infinite series

$\sum\left[(n^3+1)^\frac13-n\right]x^n$ converges?

Please help me out.

Using ratio test

$\begin{aligned}&\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(n^3+1)^{1/3}-n}{\left[\left((n+1)^3+1\right)^{1/3}-(n+1)\right]x}&>1\\\implies&\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n[\left(1+\frac1{n^3}\right)^{1/3}-1]}{n\left[\left(\left(1+\frac1n\right)^3+\frac1{n^3}\right)^{1/3}-\left(1+\frac1n\right)\right]x}&>1\\\implies&\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\left[\left(1+\frac1{3n^3}\right)-1\right]}{\left[\left(\left(1+\frac1n\right)^3+\frac1{n^3}\right)^{1/3}-(1+\frac1n)\right]x}&>1\end{aligned}$

But I can't understand how will I approximate the denominator $\left(\left(1+\frac1n\right)^3+\frac1{n^3}\right)^{1/3}$

Please help me out.

Comment: You asked this same question an hour ago and have deleted it to repost it. This type of behavior is discouraged here.

Comment: I am sorry, but no one answered it, but I got some hints from Ian, I used them to work on it and I have posted along with those works. It's not the exact copy of the previous one.

Comment: Please help me out with this approximation $[((1+\frac{1}{n})^{3}+\frac{1}{n^3})^{1/3}]$. How will I linearly approximate it.

Comment: Let $a=\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}$ and $b=n$. Then $a^3-b^3=1$. So from $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ we get that $a-b=\frac{1}{a^2+ab+b^2}$. That givee something easier to handle.

Answer (score 2):

Recall the difference of two cubes factorisation:
$$a^3 - b^3 = (a - b)(a^2 + ab + b^2).$$
Now consider the above with $a = (n^3 + 1)^{1/3}$ and $b = n$. Then,
$$((n^3 + 1)^{1/3} - n)((n^3 + 1)^{2/3} + n(n^3 + 1)^{1/3} + n^2) = n^3 + 1 - n^3 = 1.$$
Rearranging,
$$(n^3 + 1)^{1/3} - n = \frac{1}{(n^3 + 1)^{2/3} + n(n^3 + 1)^{1/3} + n^2}.$$
Try applying the ratio test again, this time on the same sum:
$$\sum \frac{1}{(n^3 + 1)^{2/3} + n(n^3 + 1)^{1/3} + n^2}x^n.$$
It should help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We know power series are absolutely convergent in their radius of convergence, hence

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[(n^3+1)^{1/3}-n\right]x^n\right|\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty 3nx^n,$$the latter having a radius of convergence $1$ (i.e., the former cannot have a radius of convergence exceeding $1$). I leave it to you to show the radius of convergence equals $1$ (but this would be my general approach).

Answer (score 0):

More hints:
for $x>0$, $ \sum_{n\ge1} x^n n^k $ converges for all $x<1$ and any $k$. Similarly, it diverges for all $x>1$ and any $k$. So the only thing you need to check is when $x=1$.